# How do I read a text file in MIT/GNU Scheme?

Tags: file-io, scheme, mit-scheme

I have been going through SICP and I would like to apply some of the concepts that I have learned so far. Namely accumulate, map and filter will help me be far more productive at work. I work mostly with CSV files and I know that MIT/GNU scheme does not support this file format. But that's ok as I can export the CSV file to txt file since txt files are supported.

Now I read Section 14 Input/Output of the manual and frankly the lack of specific examples is not helping me get started. Therefore I am hoping some of you could give me a head start. I have a text file, foo.txt, consisting of variables and observations for a list of countries. I just want to read this file into Scheme and manipulate the data. Thank you for your help. Any sample code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(call-with-input-file "my_file.txt"
  (lambda (port)
    (read port))) ; reads the file's contents
```

See the reference manual on [file ports](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/File-Ports.html#File-Ports) and on [ports](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Ports.html#Ports) in general.

Comment: Thank you igneus. I will read that section again now that you have provided a simple example. The first time I read it, the lack of specific examples made it challenging for me to understand.

Answer (score 5):

Scheme provides a few ways to read from files. You can use an 'open/close' style, as follows:

```
(let ((port (open-input-file "file.txt")))
  (display (read port))
  (close-input-port port))
```

You can also use igneus' answer, which passes the port to a procedure, and automatically closes the port for you when the procedure ends:

```
(call-with-input-file "file.txt"
  (lambda (port)
    (display (read port))))
```

Finally, my favourite, changes the current-input-port to read from the file, runs the provided procedure, closes the file and resets the current-input-port at the end:

```
(with-input-from-file "file.txt"
                      (lambda ()
                        (display (read))))
```

You will also want to read the section on [Input Procedures](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Input-Procedures.html#Input-Procedures). The "read" function used above only reads the next Scheme object from the port. There are also read-char, read-line etc. If you have read everything out of a file, you will get something that eof-object? will return true on - useful if you are looping through a file to read all the contents.

e.g. reading all the lines in a file, into a list

```
(with-input-from-file "text.txt"
  (lambda ()
    (let loop ((lines '())
               (next-line (read-line)))
       (if (eof-object? next-line) ; when we hit the end of file
           (reverse lines)         ; return the lines
           (loop (cons next-line lines) ; else loop, keeping this line
                 (read-line))))))       ; and move to next one
```

Comment: Many thanks Peter. I am following your suggestions right now and its working great. Thanks for your help.